# class not found : recursive reflection to inject dependency

Tags: php, dependency-injection, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am trying to understand some advanced concept of mvc architecture in php,like autoload with psr-4 and dependency injection container.I made a dependency injection container and load classes using composer autoload.
Whenever i run this code i get the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Class Test does not exist' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\reflection\Container\Container.php:15 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\reflection\Container\Container.php(15):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('Test') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\reflection\index.php(9):
>   Container\Container::newInstanceOf('Test') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\reflection\Container\Container.php

Seems like Container.php doesn't get classes from controller directory.I could not find out the reason behind this problem.

My directory structure is as follows :

```
-reflection Directory
  -Controller folder
    -Test.php
    -Test2.php
  -Container Directory
    -Container.php
-vendor Directory
-index.php
```

index.php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Container\Container;
use Controller\Test;
use Controller\Test2;

$test = Container::newInstanceOf('Test');

$test->testHi();
```

Container.php :

```
namespace Container;

class Container
{

     public static function newInstanceOf($class)
     {

         $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($class);

         $constructor = $reflection->getConstructor();

         if ( ! $constructor)
         {

             return new $class;

         }
         $params = $constructor->getParameters();

         if (count($params) === 0)
         {

             return new $class;

         }

         $newInstanceParams = [];

         foreach($params as $param)
         {
             if(is_null($param->getClass()))
             {
                 $newInstanceParam[] = null;

                 continue;
             }

             $newInstanceParams[] = self::newInstanceOf($param->getClass()->getName());

         }

         return $reflection->newInstanceArgs($newInstanceParams);

     }

}
```

Test.php :

```
namespace Controller;

class Test
{

    private $test2;

    public function __construct(Test2 $test2)
    {

        $this->test2 = $test2;

    }
    public function testHi()
    {
        $this->test2->test2Hi();

    }


}
```

Test2.php :

```
namespace Controller;

class Test2
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function test2Hi()
    {
       echo 'hi from test 2 !';
    }
}
```

Composer.json :

```
{
    "autoload":{

            "psr-4":{
                     "Controller\\" : "Controller",
                     "Container\\"  : "Container"

            }

    }

}
```

Comment: put your composer.json here

Comment: @AminAlizade sorry for that ! composer.json is added to the post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
$test = Container::newInstanceOf('Test');
```

to:

```
$test = Container::newInstanceOf('Controller\Test');
```

Comment: Looks like it is working ! Can you explain why it is working that way.I have already 'use Controller\Test' namepsace.Why do i need to pass the namespace to container ?

Comment: Yes, the Container know where the Controller namespace, but I think the ReflectionClass doesn't know the namespace the parameter $class living when you pass it in as a parameter. And the ReflectionClass does not have the declaration like `use Controller\Test`....

Comment: ok ! From the constructor of Test class , Test2 class is achieved.When 'Test2' is passed to $class variable ,we are not passing the namespace this time like we did first time.So how come reflection class is able to resolve Test2 class?

Comment: `var_dump($newInstanceParams);` and take a look.